# How to browse the subpages of a homepage that does not load

Tags: website-features, browser-support

Apparently the homepage of this website http://www.spe.gov.al/ loads a blank page. Is there a way to browse its subpages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Google for that. You will, at least, see pages that have been indexed by Google. The commande is: `site:www.domain.com`:

https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awww.spe.gov.al

It will returns all indexed pages that belong to this domain. In your case, it seems that all indexed pages are dead except `http://www.spe.gov.al/harta/`.

Comment: Cache is also dead. Seems the site has been down for a long time... http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.spe.gov.al

Answer (score 0):

### Browsing as a robot

If you ask to your web browser the source code of the home page (*CTRL + U* with Chrome), you can see anything.
In that case, Google can't crawl sub pages from the home page because it doesn't find any link.

### Browsing as a visitor

You can use `site:` command line in Google to see all indexed pages and find sub pages.